# The impact of using mybatis and hibernate at the same time on the first level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, mybatis, dirtyread

If I use both mybatis and hibernate, will there be dirty reads?
For example, if I use hibernate to update a certain value and commit, will I read the first-level cache when I use mybatis to read it? Will dirty reads occur?

Comment: You need to provide more information (various configurations, relevant code, etc.) if you want useful answers. Both Hibernate and MyBatis use first-level cache, but they are not shared. Also, the term "dirty-read" has a particular meaning in DB operation and should not be confused with "reading persistence tool's cached data".